# Powershell - Searching value for 32 and 64 bits in registry

Tags: powershell, registry

I currently working on powershell script who collect some datas into registry.

To perform these action, I use a similar code:

```
$Ifkeyexist = Test-Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\XXXX\YYY\ZZZ\environment\'
if ($Ifkeyexist -eq "True")
{
$GetProductHotfix = Get-ItemPropertyValue 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\XXXX\YYY\ZZZ\environment\' 'ProductHotfix'
Write-host "- Product Hotfix: $GetProductHotfix"
}
else {
write-host "- Unable to find product hotfix" -ForegroundColor red
}
}
```

Question:
in the example above, is it possible to find the value "ProductHotfix" in the 32 and 64 bit registry path?

Thanks by advance for your advices :)

Regards,

LEFBE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like below:

```
foreach ($path in 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\XXXX\YYY\ZZZ\environment', 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\XXXX\YYY\ZZZ\environment') {
    $hotfix = Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path $path  -Name 'ProductHotfix' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    # assuming you want to exit the loop at the first successfull 'hit'
    if ($hotfix) { break }
}

if ($hotfix) {
    Write-Host "- Product Hotfix: $hotfix"
}
else {
    Write-Host "- Unable to find product hotfix" -ForegroundColor Red
}
```

Comment: Thanks Theo, I will try to use this type of code :) - Just an additional question: of none one registry path exist what happens ?

Comment: @LEFBE Well... in that case variable `$hotfix` remains empty, but because of `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` you won't get exceptions thrown